# Session get lost even if I am interacting on page

Tags: session, jsf, primefaces

I'm working with primefaces 3.4.2 Javax.faces 2.1.9

My web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>45</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<p:idleMonitor id="idMonitorSession" timeout="2400000"
                onidle="dlgMensajeSessionExp.show()" />

<p:dialog header="Sesion Ended" resizable="false"
                widgetVar="dlgMensajeSessionExp" width="300" height="120"
                modal="true" closable="false" appendToBody="true">
                <center>
                    <h:outputText value="Session Ended" />
                    <h:form id="sessionForm">
                        <h:commandLink actionListener="#{user.exit()}">
                            <h:graphicImage style="border:0px" value="/resources/images/login.png"
                                width="80px" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:form>
                </center>
            </p:dialog>
```

However session get lost even if i am working in the pages, do you have any idea why is this happening,

Web Server is Websphere 7.0.0.17

Comment: How are you interacting on the page? The idleMonitor is a pure client-side thing. If nothing is send to the server, the session normally expires. So the code you show and the behaviour you see is as expected

Comment: @Kukeltje Should i add <p:ajax event="active" listener="#{bean.activeListener}" update="msg" /> and call a method just to refresh?

Comment: where do you think you should add it and why? Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Interacting with the page in such a way that the server isn't invoked via ajax or a complete form post doesn't reset the timeout against the session server side. Using ajax events for the idleMonitor should do the trick.

```
<p:idleMonitor id="idMonitorSession" timeout="2400000"
            onidle="dlgMensajeSessionExp.show()">     
  <p:ajax event="active"/>
</p:idleMonitor>
```

Edit: I noticed the "active" event doesn't fire when the mouse is moved, the user will be required to interact with the page enough to trigger this event. If it is critical to keep the server synced with the page, ajax invocations will be required more often than this event will create. You don't have to necessarily invoke a noop action on the server side, setting the event type is enough.

Another possibility is to use ajax events when the type of interactions occur that indicate your users are actively using the page. For instance, typing a long message in a text area or filtering a large data table.

```
<p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{bean.activeListener}"/>
```

Either way, the goal is to keep the server aware that the user is indeed active without flooding the server with unneeded ajax events.

Comment: Is a `listener` mandatory for the job? Theoretically just `<p:ajax event="active" />` should suffice. Or perhaps even `<p:ajax />` if `active` is already the default event of `<p:idleMonitor>`.

Comment: @BalusC You are correct that a direct action invocation isn't required. I wasn't able to get away with just <p:ajax /> as is wasn't allowed at runtime on the tech stack I'm using.